# Converting an array of values into an array of strings in JMeter

Tags: arrays, jmeter, jsr223

I have a request whose payload has a lot of data, and I want to send an array of strings as a part of it. I have fetched the array of values successfully, but they're not strings. It looks like below:

`[1155589559790260200, 30597270917880295000, 0130214252533104648]`

But I want it to be sent in this format:

`["1155589559790260200", "30597270917880295000", "0130214252533104648"]`

the part of the request where the data will look like this:

`"ids": ["1155589559790260200", "30597270917880295000", "0130214252533104648"]`

I don't want to use the toPrettyString() method, because the request body is quite large and it is difficult to edit the rest of the parameters. I just want the array of values to be converted to array of strings. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) called `foo` with the value of `[1155589559790260200, 30597270917880295000, 0130214252533104648]` and you would like to surround the numbers with quotation marks you can use [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function.

Example code would be something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('foo').replaceAll(/\b(\d+)\b/) { match\, number -> "\"$number\"" },)}
```

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: This is not working if the Ids are in this format: [test_1155589559790260200, test_30597270917880295000, test_0130214252533104648]. How to make this work for the above data?

Comment: The answer is valid for the original question, I'm not going to revisit each and every comment to provide an update for each and every use case