# Converting an array of values into an array of strings in JMeter - part 2

Tags: arrays, jmeter

[Converting an array of values into an array of strings in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76924647/converting-an-array-of-values-into-an-array-of-strings-in-jmeter)

In continuation to the above question, the code doesn't work if the data is in the below format:

[test_1155589559790260200, test_30597270917880295000, test_0130214252533104648]

How to make this work for the above data?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by changing the relevant regular expression and making the `test_` prefix a part of it:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('foo').replaceAll(/\b(test_\d+)\b/) { match\, number -> "\"$number\"" },)}
```

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy Regular Expressions - The Definitive Guide (Part 1)](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

However if you need to add quotation marks to the data presumably coming from a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) most probably the response does have these quotation marks already so it might worth taking a look at why the quotation marks are being removed and amend your Post-Processor configuration.